# ActionPeformed is repeated after I call repaint in java

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I had a button called Undo in a panel , below is the code. My problem was that after I clicked undo , the actions that needed to be executed was repeated. 
I solved the problem after I put the undo inicialization code in the constructor of my Jpanel. I understand that has something to do with repaint and propably something to do with threads , but  I would like to have a clearer explonation if possible to have a better understand.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    /*
    * Some other actions. 
    */
    undo.setLocation(535 , 680);
    undo.setSize(100 , 40);
    undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Inside Action Performed");
                gameBoard.undoMove();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    add(undo);
}
```

Comment: Never register a listener inside the paint method. Each time the component gets repainted, an additional listener gets registered !

Comment: You are supposed to add an action listener only once in the program, when you set up the components. In this case, you are adding an action listener every time you are painting the component. So you will end up with hundreds of action listeners on the hundreds of buttons. Do this **outside of the `paintComponent`**.

Comment: @Berger that seems like an answer to me, I think you can add it. @Joan also `paintComponent` sets the location and size of `undo`??? Ouch... `paintComponent` should do *only* what it says: paint the component.